# Transforming Decision Table to a web wizard/questionnaire

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt, xml-parsing

I have a decision table in excel which categorizes students in the below format. This is just a small subset, the decision table is 5-6 times bigger than this.

```
      Conditions                                Rules

Is Currently Enrolled       Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   N   Y   Y   Y   N
Is Graduating Semester      N   N   N   Y   N   N   N   Y   N   N   N   Y
Is Student Senior                       Y               Y               Y
Is Student Junior           Y               Y               Y           
Is Student Freshmen             Y               Y               Y       
Is Student Sophomore                Y               Y               Y   
Is Out of State Student     Y   Y   Y   Y                               
Is In State Student                        Y    Y   Y   Y               
Is International Student                                    Y   Y   Y   Y
Student Has Scholarship     Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y

      Actions               CA  CB  CC  CD  CE  CF  CG  CH  CI  CJ  CK  CL
```

Is there any way I can utilize such decision trees to transforming it into a wizard/questionnaire on web rather than programming this from scratch? Also, is there any other format I should transform my Decision table to, which would make it easy to transforming it into a web wizard/questionnaire?

What I mean by wizard/questionnaire is, I want to display the first question and depending on what they select I want to show the next question.

Hope I made this clear...

Comment: What is the data format of the decision table? XML? Excel? You should certainly be able to use this as data to create such a wizard - but it's up to you to decide what the HTML should look like.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The decision table is in Excel

Comment: @JohnSaunders How should I approach this? Could you point me to some resource and/or detail the steps to achieving this?

Comment: This is a very broad question. I always say start with just plain HTML, then figure out how to make it data-driven.